# Updating the Styling of a component passed in - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am fairly new to React and I am stuck in styling a component using styled components.

```
const SearchBarContainer_Button = styled.button`
      padding: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      width: 300px;
`;


<ButtonOne
  style={SearchBarContainer_Button}
  type="submit"
  className="search-bar__button"
>
  {this.props.buttonText || 'search'}
</ButtonOne>
```

Here is what I have in my ButtonOne:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button_One = styled.button`
      cursor:pointer;
      border: none;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #000;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: 900;
`;

export const ButtonOne = (props) => (
  <Button_One className={props.className}>{props.children}</Button_One>
);
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, and I would really appreciate some guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: React uses object literals for styling: `style = { padding: 10, marginLeft: 10, width: 300 };` What you have shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Hi Chris, It is compiling, I just don't see the styling being applied to my button.

Comment: Sorry, just saw that you're using a 3rd party lib called `styled-components`. In that case you need to re-read the docs on how to use it, I guess. Your first example mixes it with React's standard styling. I'd advise you to ditch `styled-components` for now and master React first.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm did you read the documentation for styled components? they are styled **COMPONENTS**

which means when you specify

```
const Button_One = styled.button`
 cursor: pointer
`
```

you need to use it as component

```
<Button_one ...props />
```

You can't pass `style={StyledComponent}` it's component not object literal with style. IF you want to extend the styled components here is the link https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles

Comment: And why you even passing `className` to styled-components? `styled-components` are superset for `className` you don't need usually both, or is there any reason why you are passing `bem` css class to the styled component?

Answer (score 2):

When used [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components), you're creating a new component with a certain styles. For your search bar, you're creating a component named `SearchBarContainer_Button` as that is your variable name. You do not need to add the style again. Try reviewing the documentation, or reference this example;

```
const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
`;
```

And to use your component `Title` with the specified styles:

```
<Title>Content of component</Title>
```